# Convert text in an NSString to it's 8-byte ASCII Hex equivalent, and store back in an NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to convert the NSString `@"2525"` to the NSString `@"0032003500320035"`.  The 8-byte ASCII value for `"2"` in hex is `"0032"` and for `"5"` it's `"0035"`.  Just to get the c-string equivalent, I tried...

```
const char *pinUTF8 = [pin cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

...but as you can see I'm struggling with this and I knew it wasn't going to be that easy.  Any tips?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Basically, you want to convert the ASCII or UTF8 representation of the string into hex.  I'm not aware of a "canned" hex converter for long strings in iOS.  (Or do you?  What do you intend to do with the hex when you have it?)

Comment: `0032` is the 2-byte ASCII value for the character `2`, not 8-byte. The 8-byte hex would be `0000000000000032`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *str = @"2525";
const char *s = [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
size_t len = strlen(s);

NSMutableString *asciiCodes = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    [asciiCodes appendFormat:@"%04x", (int)s[i]];
}

NSLog(@"%@", asciiCodes);
```

Comment: Won't that do 4 bytes per char?  You probably want `%02x`.  And it might be wise to `&` the character value with 255 as well, since characterAtIndex returns a 16-bit value.

Comment: @HotLicks If you look at the format of the output OP wants, you'll see I'm right. Bizarre, but he treats poor ASCII as UTF-16. Also, if it's really ASCII, there shall be no values greater than 255. But anyways, I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Yep, I see you are right, sorry.  It is a rather bizarre request (and I'm wondering why he wants the data that way).